# How to add discount to cart total?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add discount according to number of product in cart and this discount will apply on total of cart. Is there any other option without use of coupons?

Comment: Refer this : 1 - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-bulk-category-discount/                                                               2 - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bulk-discount/screenshots/

Comment: these plugins are working with product wise i need to add discount according to total number of products in cart.

Comment: Then you will need to do custom code for that I think..

Comment: Is there not any hook of woocommerce to add custom discounts?

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928367/how-to-create-custom-discount-for-the-cart-in-woocommerce

Comment: This only shows the discount amount but not cut the discounted price from total.

Comment: Then you will have to do custom code. you will not get ready made code I think..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_when_produts_in_cart');
function discount_when_produts_in_cart( ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count > 3 ) {
        $coupon_code = 'maryscode';
        if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount( sanitize_text_field( $coupon_code ))) {
            $woocommerce->show_messages();
        }
        echo '<div class="woocommerce_message"><strong>You have more than 3 items in your cart, a 10% discount has been added.</strong></div>';
    }
}
```

The above will apply the coupon "maryscode" to the cart if there are 4 or more products in the customers cart.

EDIT: Add the following to your css

```
.coupon {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this is working but showing coupon field and apply button and messages on cart page.

Comment: @user3714488 Go to the Woocommerce settings -> Checkout, there is an option for "Coupons" untick that box and it won't show the coupon field/apply button on the cart page.

Comment: when i untick the option the above code does not work

Comment: @user3714488, sorry about that. Retick that option and add the css I edited into my post.

Answer (score 31):

I prefer this way, cleaner I think

```
// Hook before calculate fees
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');

/**
 * Add custom fee if more than three article
 * @param WC_Cart $cart
 */
function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    if( $cart->cart_contents_count < 3 ){
        return;
    }
    
    // Calculate the amount to reduce
    $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.1;
    $cart->add_fee( 'You have more than 3 items in your cart, a 10% discount has been added.', -$discount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better approach instead of using coupon codes to clutter the backend when using dynamic discounts applied to carts.

Comment: Does this also saves in the backend order when guest user is shopping ?

Comment: If you use VAT on the site then the VAT amount is added to the discount price too. like if you have 20% VAT and the Discount price is 10 then your final discount is 12